# Solutions for the given system with fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have to solve in $\Bbb{R}$ the following system :
$$
\ \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        \frac{y}{x}+\frac{x}{y}=\frac{17}{4}  \\
        x^2-y^2=25
    \end{array}
\right.$$

For this one I am stuck, I tried to use the fact that $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$ and multiply by $x$ (or $y$) in line $1$ but fractions 'bother' me. Any hint are welcome.

Comment: Try multiplying the first equation by $xy$.  Then see if anything comes to you.

Comment: Let $r = \dfrac{y}{x}$. Then the first equation becomes $r+\dfrac{1}{r} = \dfrac{17}{45}$, i.e. $r^2-\dfrac{17}{45}r+1 = 0$, which has no real solutions. Are you sure you have written the system of equations correctly?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Arfffff, you are absolutely right. I just watched. I will edit. Sorry!

Comment: @downvoters Please share why the downvote.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Thanks you with your method I can solve my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $s=x-y$ and $t=x+y$. Then the first equation becomes
$$\frac{t-s}{t+s}+\frac{t+s}{t-s}=\frac{17}{4}$$
which with some manipulation becomes $9t^2=25s^2$, or equivalently 
$t=\pm\frac{5}{3}s$.

The second equation is $st=25$. The rest should not be difficult.

Comment: These seem like great (but contrived) substitutions. How did you come up with them? Is there a general method about what substition(s) one should use in this situation?

Comment: It has been a couple of hours since my last cup of coffee, so I do not have the imagination to make a great substitution. Comes up a lot, in various versions, most simply when we are expressing $n$ as a difference of squares.

Comment: By the way, the approach of solving for $y/x$ is more natural.

Comment: 'with some manipulation' -> multiplying by $(s+t)(s-t)$ and factor. I got it. Cool substituion, thanks a lot! +1 and accept.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$x/y=t\Rightarrow y/x=1/t$$
from first equation
$$t+1/t=17/4\iff 4t^2-17t+4=0$$
$$t_{1,2}=\frac{17\pm15}{8}=4,1/4$$
$x=4y$ or $y=4x$
from second equation
$$(4y)^2-y^2=25,y^2=5/3$$

Comment: Thanks, same method as JimmyK4542 but +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by $4xy$ gives $4x^2+4y^2=17xy$ or $4x^2-17xy+4y^2=0$, so
$(4x-y)(x-4y)=0.$

Now substitute $y=4x$ and $x=4y$ into the second equation to find the possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Write $\ds{x\ \mbox{and}\ y}$ as
$\ds{x = 5\cosh\pars{\theta}\,,\  y =5\sinh\pars{\theta}}$ such that the second equation is satisfied. With the first equation, we'll get:
\begin{align}
{17 \over 4}&={\sinh\pars{\theta} \over \cosh\pars{\theta}}
+ {\cosh\pars{\theta} \over \sinh\pars{\theta}}
={2\cosh\pars{2\theta} \over \sinh\pars{2\theta}}\ \imp\ \tanh\pars{2\theta}
={8 \over 17}
\end{align}

> $$
> \theta = \half\,{\rm arctanh}\pars{8 \over 17}
> ={1 \over 4}\,\ln\pars{1 + 8/17 \over 1 - 8/17}
> ={1 \over 4}\,\ln\pars{25 \over 9}=
> \ln\pars{\root{5 \over 3}}
> $$

\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\Large x}=5\,{\expo{\theta} + \expo{-\theta} \over 2}
={5 \over 2}\,\pars{\root{5 \over 3} + \root{3 \over 5}}
=\color{#66f}{\large{4 \over 3}\,\root{15}} \approx {\tt 5.1640} 
\\[3mm]\mbox{Similarly,}\quad
&\color{#66f}{\Large y}=5\,{\expo{\theta} - \expo{-\theta} \over 2}
={5 \over 2}\,\pars{\root{5 \over 3} - \root{3 \over 5}}
=\color{#66f}{\large{1 \over 3}\,\root{15}} \approx {\tt 1.2910} 
\end{align}

> $\ds{\large\tt\mbox{Note that}\ \pars{-x,-y}\ \mbox{is a solution too}}$.